# Concatenating dynamic year to a set string

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update an incorrect SQL function for our statistical application and am having an issue.

In the where statement I need to find records between two dates (Fiscal Years). Depending upon the current date.

So I an declaring the current date (`@currentDate DATE`).  I then need to determine the `START YEAR` if the `MONTH` is >= to 10, if so I use:

```
rm.award_date BETWEEN '10/1/' & CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @CurrentDate) >= 10 
    THEN DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) - 1 
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) END
```

Conversely to get the `END YEAR` I an using:

```
'9/30' & CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @CurrentDate) < 10 
    THEN DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) 
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) + 1 END
```

But I am getting an error that it cannot cast the `varchar` (`10/1/`) to an `int`.

How can I update this to actually concatenate the correct date to the string?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This matters as syntax will vary. SQL Server? Oracle? Access?

Comment: Sorry MSSQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator is not a string concatenation operator, but a [bitwise operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql), which will force its arguments to `int`. Hence the error you get.

Use the `+` instead, or the more standard `concat` function.

But please note that you can achieve the same with date functions in a more efficient way. For example with [`datefromparts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) (SQL Server 2012+):

```
between DateFromParts(Year(DateAdd(month, -9, @currentDate)), 10, 01) 
    and DateFromParts(Year(DateAdd(month,  3, @currentDate)),  9, 30)
```

In case you are on an older version of SQL Server, it becomes a bit more verbose:

```
between DateAdd(day,  0, DateAdd(month, 9, DateAdd(Year, Year(dateadd(month, -9, @currentDate))-1900, 0)))
    and DateAdd(day, 29, DateAdd(month, 8, DateAdd(Year, Year(dateadd(month,  3, @currentDate))-1900, 0)))
```

Comment: More efficient would be better for me for sure.  Can you lead the way and explain?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Trincot for your assistance!  Here is my current function:
'code'

Comment: I added one way to create the dates without string concatenation, which is to be avoided. (With a necessary correction, just after I posted!)

Comment: Unfortunately that function is a 2012 forward function and we (The Government) is still using 2010.  Sorry!
Guess I can use some type of dateAdd and CAST combo or something like that?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry Trincot, yea, we are on 2010.

Comment: OK, I have added support for that in my answer now. But it still does not rely on string conversion, which is what you should be aiming for.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there any way I can return the date in the function from within SQLSMS?

Comment: That would be a different question, please search first whether this was not asked before, but then go ahead and press "Ask Question".